# How to use bin/magento config:set for obscure / encrypted values

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.2

How can I use the magento CLI to set an encrypted value to a custom path that was added by a module? At the moment it seems that the CLI will add it as plain text even though the field is defined to have a type of "obscure".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field should be defined as **'sensitive'** so that it's picked up by the default sensitive settings (guidelines [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/configuration/sensitive-and-environment-settings.html)).

If you want to write the sensitive information, you should use the command (guideline [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-config-mgmt-set.html#config-cli-config-set)).

Also you can check the results with the command:

> bin/magento config:show which displays the values of any encrypted values as a series of asterisks: ******.

Comment: That seems to work on Magento 2.4, thank you! Is this compatible with older versions of Magento?

Comment: you're welcome! glad i could help :) please consider marking this as solution and as for older versions of Magento, i found this for 2.2 https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands.html, implicitly if you change the url from 2.2 to 2.3, you'll find support for 2.3.x also. However i can't trace back the support for 2.1.x, you could however dld the 2.1 version from github and check there.